# Trying to delete image from server

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have upload an image on the server and trying to delete it from server but not happening any idea how to achieve it will be appreciated.
image uploading Code

```
public void Upload1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Extract Image File Name.
    fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName1);

    if (extension.ToLower() == ".png" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpg")
    {
        string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        //Set the Image File Path.
        fileName1 = s + extension.ToLower();
        filePath1 = "~/Uploads/" + fileName1;
        //Save the Image File in Folder.
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath1));
        gvImages1.ImageUrl = "~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(filePath1);
    }
}
```

Image deleting code from server

```
public void Delete1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string delImgPath1 = gvImages1.ImageUrl;        
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(delImgPath1))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(delImgPath1);
    }
}
```

image deleting code not able to delete the code from server .

Comment: what is the value you are getting in `delImgPath1`? have you debugged?

Comment: Are you sure that the code `System.IO.File.Delete(delImgPath1);` is executed?

Comment: @sujithkarivelil following value i am getting at delImgPath1=~/Uploads/20190109103823.jpg

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no actually it skip the if condition check

Comment: That means the value in variable `delImgPath1` is not valid. You need to have a valid file path there.... `~/Uploads/20190109103823.jpg` is not a valid file path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For saving the same file in the server, you have used the `Server.MapPath` to get the server's location. then why not use the same to delete the file like the following?

```
string delImgPath1 = Server.MapPath(gvImages1.ImageUrl); // change here
if (System.IO.File.Exists(delImgPath1))
{
   System.IO.File.Delete(delImgPath1);
}
```